# Spring 'AuthenticationManager is required' xml config with Java annotation-config

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

This might be related to some of the load order issues, but I'm not certain / looking for confirmation.  I am working on a legacy project where we are not able to switch over to SpringBoot configuration, but we have updated all of the core spring jars to 4.2.x.

Whenever I start my server (running in Jetty container) with the security configuration enabled I receive the following error below [1].

**My xml config looks like this:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean class="com.company.project.config.SecurityConfiguration"/>
```

I have a sample spring-boot project where I first wrote the SecurityConfiguration, and I do not receive the exception there.

**My security configuration looks like:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableCustomSSOSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${sso.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${sso.appId}")
    private String appId;

    @Value("${sso.targetService}")
    private String target;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/scripts/**/*.{js,html}")
            .antMatchers("/bower_components/**")
            .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
            .antMatchers("/assets/**")
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
            .antMatchers("/test/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .apply(CustomSSOConfigurer.configure(host))
            .appId(appId)
            .targetService(target)
            .authenticatedUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
        .and()
            .logout()
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/*").permitAll();
    }

}
```

**The issue arises because there are no authenticationProviders configured.  So in the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` this code returns null:**

```
@Override
protected ProviderManager performBuild() throws Exception {
    if (!isConfigured()) {
        logger.debug("No authenticationProviders and no parentAuthenticationManager defined. Returning null.");
        return null;
    }
```

When I launch from spring-boot, I see the following authenticationProvider:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider@4fcf4925
```

This results in the ProviderManager being created, and ultimately the authentication manager.

**Where is this DaoAuthenticationProvider coming from?  How should I be configuring it or what xml-configuration am I missing?  Is this related to the load order?**

**Any help is greatly appreciated.**

[1] Error from server

```
2015-12-02 09:58:05,230 [WARN ] org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext [main] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An AuthenticationManager is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:835)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at com.company.core.common.configuration.Config.initContext(Config.java:753)
    at com.company.core.common.configuration.Config.initContext(Config.java:893)
    at com.company.core.common.configuration.Config.getApplicationContext(Config.java:1188)
    at com.company.core.common.ApplicationBase.initContext(ApplicationBase.java:59)
    at com.company.core.common.ApplicationBase.run(ApplicationBase.java:157)
    at com.company.core.web.ApplicationBaseInitListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationBaseInitListener.java:58)
    at com.company.project.core.web.ICFAplicationBaseListener.contextInitialized(ICFAplicationBaseListener.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1312)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at com.company.project.jetty.StartICFServer.startServer(StartICFServer.java:93)
    at com.company.project.jetty.StartICFServer.main(StartICFServer.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An AuthenticationManager is required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 36 more
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add in your xml file this code :

```
<security:authentication-manager/>
```

under

```
<bean class="com.company.project.config.SecurityConfiguration"/>
```